# runtime: goroutine stack exceeds 1000000000-byte limit, when save struct to json

Tags: go

I've defined a go struct of Trie data structure.

```
type Node struct {
Val      rune
IsWord   bool
IsRoot   bool
Parent   *Node
Children map[rune]*Node
}
type Trie struct {
Root *Node
}
trie := algorithms.InitTrie()
```

However, it raises an error

```
runtime: goroutine stack exceeds 1000000000-byte limit
fatal error: stack overflow
runtime stack:
runtime.throw(0x10e9426, 0xe)
/usr/local/go/src/runtime/panic.go:605 +0x95
runtime.newstack(0x0)
/usr/local/go/src/runtime/stack.go:1050 +0x6e1
runtime.morestack()
/usr/local/go/src/runtime/asm_amd64.s:415 +0x86
```

When I insert some words and save it into json file.

```
fmt.Println(json.Marshal(&trie))
```

Comment: Most likely you have an endless "recursion" so your code runs out of stack.

Comment: Most likely you have a cycle (a node pointing to itself as a child, either directly or indirectly) in your Trie.

Comment: Any suggested solution?

Comment: Post a [mcve]. Most likely the "bug" is in `Trie.MarshalJSON()` or `Node.MarshalJSON()`.

Comment: yes, analyze your code, find where the cycle is created and break it. Do you have a custom JSON marshaller for Trie?

Comment: This is a genuine question. Why on earth someone thinks it is 'off-topic'?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that each `Node` has a reference to it's parent, as well as to it's children.  So when it encodes a child, for the parent field, it encodes the parent again, and for that parent, it encodes the child again, etc.  A simple solution would be to simply not use the `Parent` field when encoding

```
Parent   *Node `json:"-"`
```

This will prevent the cycle.

https://play.golang.org/p/BdVgMNjlZOa